# AWS Fargate delay

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

We use AWS Fargate to serve about just 700 requests per day with our API, there is no database or any other external dependencies.

Most of the time it works well and responds adequately, but sometimes the response takes 10 seconds and we get a request time out. We've checked everything and we have just 1 assumption, which we want to check if it can take place.

Our assumption is that Fargate de-allocates all resources when there are no requests and sometimes it can take a while till containers resume running. Can that be the cause?

Comment: "Our assumption is that Fargate de-allocates all resources when there are no requests and sometimes it can take a while till containers resume running. Can that be the cause?" No that's not how Fargate works. You have the entire resources (CPU and RAM) that you specify reserved the entire time the task is running.

Answer (score 2):

When you start a task with Fargate we allocate capacity and never release it until the task stops. So your assumption is not the root cause. Consider that a Fargate task may take around 30/40 seconds to start (possibly more depending on the image size) so it doesn't look like what you are seeing (10 seconds delay) is a symptom of a task starting either. If you have enabled CloudWatch Container Insights for the cluster, you could try to see if there is any particular activity (peaks, tasks being deployed etc) at the time you see your delay/timeout. Assuming this is an ECS service that scales in and out I am wondering if there is any specific activity being carried out when you experience the issue. It's hard to suggest anything without further elements but definitely your theory isn't what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I'll check cloudwatch today.
No side activity is being performed, my next assumption is that when it is backed by spot instances, they may be in the starting phase.

Comment: The stop/start mechanics between on-demand and spot instances is not that different but spot instances could be stopped more abruptly and that *might* have something to do with the timeout you are seeing (albeit it would not be my first pick)